# Can't enable script component on a prefab instance in Unity

Tags: unity

Prefab structure:

```
 MainObject (parent; prefab instance in the scene)
 |-Child
 |-Child
 |-Triggers
     |-Trigger1
```

**MainObject** has: **ScriptIWantToEnable** (Script) component *(Disabled)*

**Trigger1** has: **ScriptThatTriesToEnableIt** (Script) component

Hello,

I'm trying to enable a script component on a prefab instance(**MainObject**) from a child object script component(**Trigger1**). For some reason though it doesn't get enabled. Run-time error shows up and the game breaks. Trigger works fine, up until the "enable" part. I checked it with the Debug.Log(). The **MainObject** is in the Hierarchy view already when the game starts.

Error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object ScriptThatTriesToEnableIt.Update () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/ScriptThatTriesToEnableIt.cs:30)

Part of the code in **ScriptThatTriesToEnableIt** that tries to enable the **ScriptIWantToEnable** script component of **MainObject**:

```
 public class ScriptThatTriesToEnableIt : MonoBehaviour {
     public GameObject MainObjectRef; //MainObject prefab instance drag&dropped in the Inspector

     void Update() {
         // if triggered
         MainObjectRef.GetComponent<ScriptIWantToEnable>().enabled = true; //breaks here and throws the error
     }
 }
```

Comment: There are two possible places you could get a null reference exception here: 1. if MainObjectRef is null, 2. If GetComponent<ScriptIWantToEnable>() returns null. Check each of these possibilities on a separate line to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: @DMGregory Yes it says that GetComponent<ScriptIWantToEnable>() returns null. Can I not reference and enable disabled script components?

Comment: @DMGregory also I don't believe this is a duplicate question. I've scanned the web looking specifically for enabling a disabled script during run-time and only results that came up were dealing with disabling an enabled component. My problem is the reverse.

Comment: Your problem is that you're calling `GetComponent<ScriptIWantToEnable>()` on an object that doesn't have a `ScriptIWantToEnable` component attached. That's the only condition in which `GetComponent` returns null. The `MainObjectRef` might not hold the value you think it does on every instance. The description above isn't enough for us to reproduce your problem in a new empty project (tested: no errors when I run the enabling script), so the generic troubleshooting advice for NullReferenceExceptions is your best bet until you edit the question to include a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Comment: @DMGregory ScriptIWantToEnable is there, I can see it in the Inspector. There's another script component attached to MainObject which I try to enable as well and it works.

Comment: I'll repeat: I cannot reproduce the problem you describe with what you've shown above. So some detail of your setup must differ from what's described in the question. You're the only one in a position to investigate that. Try to reproduce the problem in a new, empty project, and edit your question to include the exact steps and complete code needed to reproduce it this way.

Comment: So this is a pretty common issue in unity, what you need to do is in the script of the component you wish to start disabled and enable at will is leave the component checked (so its enabled) then in its start method set it to disabled.      `void Start() { this.enabled = false; }`Then from another script you can simply flick the script on and off.

The key thing to remember is even if you want it disabled until you turn it on, the component must be active on the object then have the script disable itself that way you get the reference to the component and can disable/enable at will.